# GridBagLayout not filling JPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am building a toolbar for a program using GridBagLayout, but even using weightx and fill, the components are not the sizes they should be and they are not filling the JPanel.

For instance, when the total size of jidest.x_size is 1920, the total size of the components is 1776

```
package jide.parts;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import jide.jidest;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class BottomBar extends JPanel implements MouseListener{
JPanel charCountPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel lineCountPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel cursorPositionPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel spacer1 = new JPanel();
JPanel spacer2 = new JPanel();
JPanel spacer3 = new JPanel();
JPanel morespace = new JPanel();
JLabel charCount = new JLabel("charcount");
JLabel lineCount = new JLabel("linecount");
JLabel cursorPosition = new JLabel("TEST:TEST");
public BottomBar(){
    this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    charCountPanel.setToolTipText("Click here for more complete stats");
    lineCountPanel.setToolTipText("Click here for more complete stats");
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int) jidest.x_size,20));
    setBackground(Color.red);
    cursorPositionPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    cursorPositionPanel.add(cursorPosition);
    //cursorPositionPanel.setSize(50,20);
    lineCountPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    lineCountPanel.add(lineCount);
    //lineCountPanel.setSize(50,20);
    charCountPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    charCountPanel.add(charCount);
    //charCountPanel.setSize(50,20);
    morespace.setSize((int) (jidest.x_size-156),20);
    //add(cursorPositionPanel);
    spacer1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    //spacer1.setSize(1,20);
    spacer2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    //spacer2.setSize(1,20);
    spacer3.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    //spacer3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1,20));
    //size is 156, width is 7
    gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.weighty=1;
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.weightx=(1.0)/jidest.x_size;
    add(spacer1,gbc);
    gbc.gridx=2;
    gbc.weightx=(50.0)/jidest.x_size;
    add(cursorPositionPanel,gbc);
    gbc.gridx=3;
    gbc.weightx=(1.0)/jidest.x_size;
    add(spacer2,gbc);
    gbc.gridx=4;
    gbc.weightx=(50.0)/jidest.x_size;
    add(lineCountPanel,gbc);
    gbc.gridx=5;
    gbc.weightx=(1.0)/jidest.x_size;
    add(spacer3,gbc);
    gbc.gridx=6;
    gbc.weightx=(50.0)/jidest.x_size;
    add(charCountPanel,gbc);
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.gridx=0;
    gbc.weightx=(jidest.x_size-153)/jidest.x_size;
    add(morespace,gbc);
    System.out.println((spacer1.getWidth()+cursorPositionPanel.getWidth()+spacer2.getWidth()+lineCountPanel.getWidth()+spacer3.getWidth()+morespace.getWidth())+" should be " + jidest.x_size);
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {

}

}
```

Comment: Post an [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: `weightx` does not specify the exact with of a component.  It is a relative value indicating the distribution of extra space if the container’s size exceeds its preferred size.  In fact, since the values are relative to each other, you can remove `/jidest.x_size` from every weightx value and you will get the same result.

Comment: It looks as you have missed to set gridy at the very beginning. Give it a try without using the gridweights, this is how many rows or columns a component spawns

Answer (score 1):

In future, please post an MCVE. This works to spread the components across the width of the bar.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class BottomBarGUI {

    private JComponent ui = null;

    BottomBarGUI() {
        initUI();
    }

    public void initUI() {
        if (ui != null) {
            return;
        }

        ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4, 4));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));

        ui.add(new BottomBar());
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                BottomBarGUI o = new BottomBarGUI();

                JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}

class BottomBar extends JPanel {

    JPanel charCountPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel lineCountPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel cursorPositionPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel spacer1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel spacer2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel spacer3 = new JPanel();
    JPanel morespace = new JPanel();
    JLabel charCount = new JLabel("charcount");
    JLabel lineCount = new JLabel("linecount");
    JLabel cursorPosition = new JLabel("TEST:TEST");

    public BottomBar() {
        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = .5;
        charCountPanel.setToolTipText("Click here for more complete stats");
        lineCountPanel.setToolTipText("Click here for more complete stats");
        setBackground(Color.red);
        cursorPositionPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        cursorPositionPanel.add(cursorPosition);
        lineCountPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        lineCountPanel.add(lineCount);
        charCountPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        charCountPanel.add(charCount);
        spacer1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        spacer2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        spacer3.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        add(spacer1, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        add(cursorPositionPanel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        add(spacer2, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 3;
        add(lineCountPanel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 4;
        add(spacer3, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 5;
        add(charCountPanel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
    }
}
```